# Помогите исправить код решения задачи на python

Tags: python

В магазине продается мастика в ящиках по a кг (тип 1), b кг (тип 2) и c кг (тип 3). Как купить ровно N кг мастики, не вскрывая ящики? Сколькими способами можно это сделать? **ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕ СПИСКОВ ЗАПРЕЩЕНО**

> Входные данные: Входная строка содержит четыре числа, разделённые
>   пробелами: a , b , c и N .
>
> Выходные данные: В первой строке нужно вывести число K способов,
>   которыми можно купить заданное количество мастики ( N кг), не вскрывая
>   ящики. В каждой из последующих K строчек программа должна вывести
>   (через пробелы) три числа, ka , kb и kc : количество ящиков 1, 2 и 3
>   типов для каждого из K вариантов закупки. Варианты должны выводиться в
>   лексикографическом порядке: сначала варианты с наименьшим значением ka
>   , для одинаковых ka – сначала варианты с наименьшим значением kb и
>   т.д.

Примеры входные данные

```
15 17 21 185
```

Выходные данные:

```
5 

0 1 8 

1 10 0 

3 7 1

5 4 2 

7 1 3
```

Мой код, который я смог написать, но используя списки, как теперь сделать тоже самое без списка?

```
a, b, c, n = map(int, input().split())
def f():
    for i in range(n // a + 1):
        for j in range(n // b + 1):
            r = n - (i * a + j * b)
            if r >= 0 and r % c == 0:
                yield i, j, r // c
result = list(f())
print(len(result))
for row in result:
    print(*row)
```

Comment: Мне же еще нужно вывести количество этих оветов

Comment: Гуглите слова "рекурсия", "задача о рюкзаке" и "динамическое программирование"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Списки запрещены, но не запрещены итераторы и генераторы. Вариант общий, для любого количества типов упаковок:

```
from operator import floordiv, mul
from itertools import tee, accumulate, repeat, product

types = (15, 17, 21)
n = 185

variants = (map(mul, range(n//t + 1), repeat(t)) for t in types)
count = filter(lambda x: sum(x) == n, product(*variants))
to_len, result = tee(map(floordiv, c, types) for c in count)

print(sum(1 for _ in to_len))
for r in result:
    print(*r)
```

Хотя можете в `tee` завернуть и свою функцию:

```
...
to_len, result = tee(f())

print(sum(1 for _ in to_len))
for r in result:
    print(*r)
```

Comment: Все правильно, но не плохо бы оптимизировать)

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b, c, n = map(int, input().split())
def f():
x=0
for i in range(n // a + 1):
    for j in range(n // b + 1):
        r = n - (i * a + j * b)
        if r >= 0 and r % c == 0:
            x+=1
print(x)
for i in range(n // a + 1):
    for j in range(n // b + 1):
        r = n - (i * a + j * b)
        if r >= 0 and r % c == 0:

            print( i, j, r // c,end="")
            print()
f()
```